# Check string for numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, numbers

How to check if string contains numbers in Python?

I have a variable which I am convert to float, but I want to make if statement, to convert it to float only if it contains only numbers.

Comment: One more thing, the number in variable is like "0.123"

Comment: That is still valid for conversion to a float

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just convert it and catch the exception if it fails.

```
s = "3.14"
try:
  val = float(s)
except ValueError:
  val = None
```

Comment: I think this is fastest approach.

Comment: This let's **"NaN"** (Not a Number) through. To explicitly check for those use `math.isnan(s)`.

Comment: @razz0 makes a good point. This approach also allows "inf" and "-inf" through, which aren't numbers either; these can be checked with `math.isinf`. While not numbers, all three are valid floats, so whether to include them or not will probably depend on the intended usage of those floats.

Comment: how do you do this inside a filter() function with a lambda?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a try-except block to determine if it is a number. That way if s is a number the cast is successful, and if it isn't you catch the ValueError so your program doesn't break.

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Since you explained the most, your answer is better! Thank you both, Michael and Hunter!

Answer (score 2):

You could also extract numbers from a string.

```
import string
extract_digits = lambda x: "".join(char for char in x if char in string.digits + ".")
```

and then convert them to float.

```
to_float = lambda x: float(x) if x.count(".") <= 1 else None
```

```
>>> token = "My pants got 2.5 legs"
>>> extract_digits(token)
'2.5'
>>> to_float(_)
2.5
>>> token = "this is not a valid number: 2.5.52"
>>> extract_digits(token)
'2.5.52'
>>> to_float(_)
None
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not the built-in `.isdigit()` for this. Compact, no `try` statements, and super fast:

```
string = float(string) if string.isdigit() else string
```

When considering error handling in Python, I believe it was Master Yoda who said, "There is no try. Do or do not."

Answer (score 1):

Michael Barber's answer will be best for speed since there's no unnecessary logic.  If for some reason you find you need to make a more granular assessment, you could use the Python standard library's regular expression module.  This would help you if you decided, for example, that you wanted to get a number like you described but had additional criteria you wanted to layer on.

```
import re
mystring = '.0323asdffa'

def find_number_with_or_without_decimal(mystring):
    return re.findall(r"^\.?\d+", mystring)

In [1]: find_number_with_or_without_decimal(mystring)
Out[1]: ['.0323']
```

The regular expression says, 'find something that starts with up to one decimal ('^' means only at beginning of line and the '?' means up to one; the decimal is escaped with a '\' so it won't have its special regular expression meaning of 'any character') and has any number of digits.  Good luck with Python!